# what is the least nuber of selections to have probability greater than or equal to 1/2?

Tags: probability

what is the least number of random selections you have to make from the numbers  1  to  7  such that the probability of selecting at least one  5  and at least one number from the set  2,4,6  is at least  1/2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the number you're looking for is the least number of random selections you have to make from the numbers $\ 1\ $ to $\ 7\ $ such that the probability of selecting at least one $\ 5\ $ and at least one number from the set $\ 2,4,6\ $ is at least $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $.

The probability that there are no $5$s in a random selection of $\ n\ $ such numbers is $\ \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n\ $, the probability that there are no $2$s, $4$s or $6$s is $\ \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n\ $, and the probability that there are no $2$s, $4$s, $5$s or $6$s is $\ \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n\ $. By the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability of having *either* no $5$s *or* no $2$s, $4$s or $6$s is $\ \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n+ \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n\ $. Thererfore, the probability of having at least one $5$ and at least one of the numbers $2$, $4$, or $6$ is $\ 1+ \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n\ $.  Elementary calculation shows that $\ 1+ \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n<\frac{1}{2}\ $ for $\ n\le 5\ $, but $\ 1+ \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^6-\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^6-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^6=\frac{67626}{117649}> \frac{1}{2}\ $, so you need to select at least $6$ people to achieve your desired probability.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation